# How to force file processing on one node without splitting?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is it possible to force file processing on one node without splitting? I tried to use AtomicFileProcessing set on true, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Setting

```
[SqlUserDefinedExtractor(AtomicFileProcessing = true)]
```

should work. Can you please contact me directly (mrys at msft) and provide more information on what does not, so we can investigate?

Comment: Hi! I can send You a code of my extractors and script, also joblinks and screens if necessary. Where should I send you this data (new question on msdn?)?

Comment: Send it to mrys at the official Microsoft dot com address. Thanks!

Comment: I sent You the necessary information by e-mail. Let me know what is causing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Could you confirm that the mechanism AtomicFileProcessing  does not work correctly for my issue at this moment, and it is not the fault of my code? I would like to know whether to look for a bug in my code or wait patiently for yours bugfix and in the meanwhile, try to circumvent this issue.

Comment: We are still investigating. My apologies for the long time, but the engineering team is busy with some important milestones. You are on a thread now with them and I hope they can find the issue. I am on vacation this month, so it will take a bit until I reply.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my job, I am using custom [user defined operators](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-develop-user-defined-operators/) for data processing, and it does not split data. You can  also try this option.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not solution for my problem. I need to read data from large file (2GB) with custom format, where data for row columns are saved in many lines of file. When extractors splits the file, the data for one row are in different file extents. When i read file data, line by line parallely, the results rowset is not ordered like in file, so i cant combine my data. I used user defined extractors with AtomicFileProcessing set on true, but it doesnt work.

Comment: I think you can do this using custom applier. Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358176/custom-parallel-extractor-u-sql/36444543#36444543